# How can I shrink my large texture so that it stays centered?

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

When I shrink my large texture down, it doesn't shrink the image. It just cuts off the image starting from the bottom right and going up diagonally.

This is how I am drawing the sprite:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Tiles[0].TileTexture, new Vector2(x * TileWidth, y * TileHeight), Color.White);
```

This is the base image I'm testing with.

[image]

This is what it looks like at 16,16

[image]

And 64,64

[image]

Comment: Did TileWidth and TileHeight same as real image width and height?

Comment: @Silveor No. Maybe I'm doing this wrong. But when I was doing this before, I had an image that was 16x16. And I want the player to be able to zoom in on the tiles. But since 16,16 is so small, it would make the image look very pixelated and bad. So I thought it was best to use a higher res image and just scale it down so when they zoomed, it would look fine. Is this not the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use image 16x16 then cell size should be 16x16. But if you want draw 64x64 image in cell 16x16 you should scale image down to 16x16, but in this case there will be no difference between in 64x64 and 16x16 source images. Or make cells 64x64 pixels.

What about zoom you can use only integer scale, like 2x, 3x and so on. Not allow non-integer scale to avoid image distortion.

SpriteBatch.Draw has [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx).
To scale image as you want you can use overload 1, 2 or 3 with destination rectangle as second parameter:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(
    tileTexture,
    new Rectange(x * TileWidth, y * TileHeight, TileWidth, TileHeight),
    Color.White);
```

Source image will be stratched to rectangle.

Or you can use on of two last overloads to scale image

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(
    tileTexture,
    new Vector2(x * TileWidth * scaleX, y * TileHeight * scaleY),
    null,
    Color.White,
    0,
    Vector2.Zero,
    new Vector2(scaleX, scaleY),
    SpriteEffects.None,
    0);
```

Also, if you just need fill background with one same tile you can call spritebatch begin methos with any wrap [SemplerState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate_members.aspx) paramether (PointWrap better as for me) and draw tile once like this:
SpriteBatch.Draw(
    tileTexture,
    new Rectange(0, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height),
    Color.White);